# Don't we need Biblically definitive eisegesis to Exegete properly?

Tags: exegesis, sola-scriptura, word-study

I've been looking at some of the thoughts on eisegesis and it seems that the general tone is always negative when the term comes up. However, when we read the bible in an Exegetical way in order to expose the text we must understand those words we read and phrases used through a biblical lens; thus in some capacity this is an eisegetical application that comes from foundational exegesis able to be factualized by proof of witness from the Scripture alone.
Therefore, is it not correct to say that we use both Exegesis and Eisegesis in our approach to understanding Scripture and that this is a positive use of the term?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  This site focuses on questions about the many Christian faiths, traditions, and denomintaions.  Thus, your question doesn't appear to be about *Christianity,* per-se.  I'll leave it up to the more experienced members of the site to judge, but you might consider asking this question on [hermeneutics.se].

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that stack...Ill join it too!

Comment: Good question. Welcome to the Stack Exchange (SE). I agree with JBH: your question is more suited for Biblical Hermeneutics SE, which I encourage you to join. Nevertheless, I'll post an answer here to get the ball rolling. Don

Comment: Biblical hermeneutics has declared this same question not appropriate for there forum either: due to it lacking a specific scripture to apply hermeneutics to.

Comment: Regrettably this fascinating question, which I would love to dig into, is going to be opinion based and so off topic.

Comment: I love the question, and I believe you are on to something that is quietly recognized, but not often mentioned, precisely because "eisegesis" is a negative term. But as DJ said, it's too opinion based for this site. Perhaps a version of it can work on https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/. Here's a similar question of my own there: [Can the term “eisegesis” apply to the interpretation of Old Testament passages as prophecies specifically of Jesus?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/17165/can-the-term-eisegesis-apply-to-the-interpretation-of-old-testament-passages-a)

Comment: You have enough rep points now, so I'd love to hear your thoughts in chat. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room Ping me with `@fredsbend`.